# Failed report downloading due to network error- Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have the shiny application deployed on the `Rshiny pro server(1.5.2)`. The application processes the `excel files` and generates the report(using `RMarkdown`) in the form of word document(having text content, tables and graphs).

**Success case:** Application does some heavy computations on the input data(for example: for 12 data points) and it takes approx. 30 to 45 seconds for it. These computation happens on `downloadHandler` action. The `size` of the report which being generated is around `1.2 MB`. Everything works perfectly in such scenario.

**Failure case:**  Application does some heavy computations on the input data(for example: for 14 data points) and it takes approx. more than 50 seconds for it. Now, during these computations (report generation) it's showing the network error on the UI only. Despite this error on the UI, in the back-end the report file is getting generated, but the generated report doesn't get downloaded(it shows failed report downloading due to network error)

**I am looking for help regarding-**

1. What can be the reason of getting the network error?
2. Is it because the `session timeout`?
3. Is there any file size(file getting generated during report generation) limit for `Rshiny pro server` or `downloadHandler` action?

Comment: Since you have the Pro Version you should ping the devs at `Rstudio` directly , they will be on it like white on rice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating and trying out different options I have found the root cause for the network error issue.

I have posted the the answer for the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300285/user-session-is-getting-interrupted-after-approx-45-seconds/45318121#45318121). Although I would like to answer above mentioned questions quickly.

1. **Root cause of the network error:**  The `http_keepalive_timeout` parameter was not defined in the `server configuration` and the default value for `http_keepalive_timeout` parameter is `45 seconds`.That's why it was showing the network error approx. after 45 seconds.
2. Yes. It was because of session time out. The `http_keepalive_timeout` is the parameter which defines the active session time between the user and server.
3. No. As per my knowledge, there is no file size limit.